# how to add multiple columns in listbox?

Tags: java, gwt, listbox

I want to create a listbox in gwt , which will contain two columns- say, name and sirname.These both columns should be visible. When I will select an item from listbox ,  I should be able to get both these values. Also, is it possible to add column name in listbox which will remain unclickable? 
I have tried this-

```
ListBox allRecs=new ListBox();
allRecs.addItem(name,sirname);
```

but here, sirname remains invisible.

Thanks

Comment: here `sirname` is value of `name` item. Why you don't try it by appending `sirname` and `name` and replace it in place of `name`?

Comment: cause i want to add column headers also. And these headers should be unclickable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with a plain ListBox which is wrapper for something like this:

```
select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Plain GWT does not offer this out of the box.
But you can create a textfield and a button (the button will show a popup with a table).
There you can define as many columns as you like, make any rows you want unclickable etc.